# Unexpected non-linear response of operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, distortion, non-linear

I have a resistive sensor that I'd like to use to generate an amplified voltage in a small range.  I'd also like to shift/offset that range up and down with the use of a DAC to kind of "zoom in" to pre-defined regions during operation using an op-amp.

I should also note that the sensor does not inherently have any AC component and is not expected to change quickly (similar to a thermistor reacting to temperature changes).

I came up with this circuit to test:
[image: tested schematic]

After some initial troubleshooting, I realized I was exceeding the upper input common-mode range of VDD–1.1V=1.9V which is why I added U1, R6, R7, R8, R9.  This allowed me to measure ~0V to ~3V for "Vsensor" and "Vdac" and test "Vout" at specific ranges.

By solving the circuit, I derived the theoretical output voltage to be:
\begin{align}
       V_{out} &= \frac{-R_2}{R_1}*V_{sensor} + \frac{R_5*(R_1+R_2)*(R_3*V_{DAC}+R_4*V_{cc})}{R_1*(R_3*R_4 + R_3*R_5 + R_4*R_5)}
\end{align}

After running through several values of "Vsensor" between 1.57V and 1.85V for a constant "Vdac" of 2.9V, I noticed the error between the theoretical and actual "Vout" was poor - as bad -38%. I realize this is outside of the opamp linear spec, but an -18% error when Vout=0.15V seems too high when I expect it to be in the linear range.

[image: Vout error chart]
[image: Input/Output table]

The [MCP607 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11177f.pdf) states the maximum input common mode voltage is 1.9V (for 3V supply) and I applied ~1.69V so I don't suspect that is the issue.  It also states the output voltage is linear when it is at least 100mV away from the rails.

I tried adjusting the values of R3, R4, R5 so that the parallel resistance is close to R1||R2 with the thought that the input bias currents could be leading to additional input offset errors. Although the error was not improved, the sign was opposite (now Vsensor was 30% *higher* than expected).

I have tried again at Vdac set to 1.5V (worst error was -17%) and again at 0.1V (worst error was +11%).  It seems the error is always the worst when Vsensor is highest and converges to 0% as Vsensor decreases.

I could use some help in troubleshooting.  Any ideas what could cause this?  Perhaps I'm not considering other key specs in the datasheet?

Thank you!

EDIT: I removed references to "difference amplifier" and instead called it op-amp

UPDATE: I tried removing the capacitor (C3), cleaning residual flux from pcb, and even removed U1 and connected PSU directly to "Vsensor" and "Vdac".  Unfortunately, the error remained high at 25%. I input my values that I listed above into a PWL to simulate in LTspice and saw the worst error was ~2% and averaged ~0.6%. My search continues.

===============================================================

UPDATE:
Rather than post my own answer and close this discussion, I decided to post an update to see what further contributions/improvements could be made. Furthermore, I still have more testing to determine if this behavior will be acceptable. Once that is complete, I will post an answer and close the discussion.

TLDR; By eliminating the trimpots and the amplifiers after them, I was able to reduce the error from ~30mV down to ~10mV.

After reviewing all the responses, I took a step back and tried to think through this again. To try and simplify the test setup as much as possible, I removed U1/R3/R5 and shorted R4. Then I connected alternate PSU channels directly as "Vsensor" and Vdac". I was happy to see that the measured "Vout" was within 3mV of the expected value throughout the range.

After further review, I believe part of my issue was with the trimpots themselves since I noticed them drifting a little over time. They are multi-turn ones but residual internal tension and disturbances while taking measurements may have caused the wiper to move slightly. The following 2x gain stage would only make it worse. Since I took my measurements one at a time with ~10s of averaging, there could've been enough time for things to change enough to be problematic.

I eliminated the pots and U1, restored R3/R4/R5 back to the original values, and connected my PSU as the two inputs as follows: same as OP but without pots/U1
[image: new sch without pots/U1]

After testing multiple points in three ranges: results in table and chart formats The parts in green are meant to signify when "Vout" is in the linear range (at least 100mV away from the rails).
[image: results using PSU in table and chart forms]

As @Jonk and @Spehro Pefhany mentioned above, the resistor tolerance also contributes errors. Moving forward, I'll look to incorporate a more stable reference voltage rather than base things off Vcc. I may also consider using 0.1% resistors.

Thank you, everyone, for your help!

As stated above, I will still test and look for further improvements and welcome any additional feedback that might arise. Once I complete my testing and am confident the issue has been resolved, I'll close the topic.

Comment: I thought I might add for your consideration what happens with 2% resistor values (I can compute it for other tolerances) are used for R3, R4, and R5. [These are the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSbAt.png) Worth a quick thought in addition to everything else.

Comment: did you use LTSpice or PSpice to simulate your circuit ? You will find the spice model here : https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MCP607, under "SPICE Model for MCP606/7/8/9 Devices"

Comment: @jonk Thanks, I'll look into this.

Comment: @Arthur Chassande I appreciate the suggestion.  I downloaded it and am playing with it now.  It didn't work right away, but I found a work-around for the time being from here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/286441/318050

Answer (score 1):

> *Unexpected non-linear response of \$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{difference amplifier}}}\$*

<sub>This was the question title before the OP changed it 17 hours after my answer</sub>

and

> *I could use some help in troubleshooting. Any ideas what could cause
> this? Perhaps I'm not considering other key specs in the datasheet?*

Your difference amplifier is badly designed. If you want to measure a difference accurately the resistors in the inverting limb need to have the same ratio as the resistors in the non-inverting limb. So in this image, R4/R3 is the same in both limbs: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/opamp-opamp21.gif).

Comment: Although my circuit is meant to do some subtraction and amplification, I don't think "difference amplifier" was the right term for me to use.  I updated my post above to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the system is made of only linear components doesnt mean the response will be necessarily linear.Take this circuit for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3uN9A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output voltage will not be a linear function of the position of the potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of error as a percentage of voltage is more than a bit misleading (and nonlinear).

It's about -30mV for small outputs decreasing to about -9mV for outputs near the positive rail.

As a percentage of output range, then it's -1% to -0.3%. Pretty much what you'd expect with 1% resistors and without measuring the 3V offset reference (which has a bit more effect on the output than Vdac).

A 1% error in Vcc (2.99V rather than 3.00V) will more than account for the 30mV shift. Typically you'd want to use a very stable reference rather than the supply voltage, or get rid of it entirely since you have a DAC feeding the offset.

Since the original question was about *linearity* and you're still using the % reading .. based on the first group of additional data posted, here is the *deviation* from linearity of your error (from a least-squares fit). Seems to be well within +/-0.04% F.S.

[image]

Comment: I can see how the error calculated as a percentage is misleading.  Doing this does exaggerate the problem which helps me find potential issues.  The difference in voltages is small like you mentioned, so I am still looking to find a way to reduce it further.

Comment: I suggest you measure the voltage at the non-inverting input of the op-amp U2A. That will help you figure things out. Also analyze the sensitivity of the output to each variable, resistor tolerance (and op-amp offset voltage). All small effects but when  you are subtracting two numbers and multiplying by a large gain the errors get multiplied, even as a % of full scale. You can look at the error as an offset and a gain error, and deviations from that model will show you any nonlinearity.

Answer (score 0):

U1A and U1B are configured for a gain of 2.  They are trying to make a 6 V output while powered by a 3 V source.  That will not work.

A conventional, non-rail-to-rail opamp needs around +/-2 V of headroom above and below the maximum signal excursions to meet published performance specs (older ones more, newer ones less).  The signals at pins 1 and 7 have a max range from 0 V to +6 V, so the power rails would have to be +8 V and -2 V, not +3 V and 0 V.

The same applies to U2A, which looks like it has a forward gain of just over 10 for the Vsensor signal.

I'm not familiar with the MPC607, so its headroom req might be less.  True R-R opamps have lower headroom requirements, but the power rails always must exceed the required signal swing, even if only by 0.1 V.

Comment: The MCP607 is a rail-to-rail op amp, so it only needs a few dozen mV of headroom.

Comment: I am not using the full range of the pots - only about half in this configuration due to the 2x gain.  I mainly did this to easily adjust the voltages and the op-amp gives me a low output impedance.